# Multiple portfolios with one custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pages, page-template

I wonder what's the right way of creating portfolio website (with as many portfolio pages I want). Usually I create page template that displays posts with category = `Portfolio` or with posts from Portfolio Custom Post Type. But what if I want multiple portfolios on my site? I know I can do it for example thru Theme Options page by assigning category to every portfolio page, but maybe there is a better way? 
Can I build mechanism like that:

1. I add page and choose "Portfolio" template.
2. After choosing template custom meta box appears. Inside custom box I have list of categories from my Portfolio Custom Post Type and I can choose which of the categories are displayed in this portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best, most WordPress friendly solution is to use the default template hierarchy.

If you're using a custom post type and default categories, you first need to get the post type into the category (and tag) archive pages. [This support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page) does that.

Now, you can see the portfolio items at yoursite.com/category/web-design, where "category" is the base category slug set on Settings > Permalinks and "web-design" would be the slug of a category denoting a specific portfolio.

If you're using a custom taxonomy, you can control the slug better and have something like yoursite.com/portfolios/web-design. (Note that "portfolios" is plural. Make sure it doesn't overlap with an existing slug on your site.)

Finally, to customize the results, you use the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). If you're using categories, then you can either edit all category pages with `category.php` (or create it based on `archive.php`) or `create category-web-design.php` (to edit a specific category template). If you're using a custom taxonomy, use the file `taxonomy-portfolios.php` for the whole custom taxonomy or `taxonomy-portfolios-web-design.php` for the specific term.

This is how WordPress is designed to be used, so I can't think of a better, more manageable way to handle this.

Comment: @smogg if this solved your problem, make sure to accept it as the answer. Otherwise, update your question and explain why this didn't work.